# Connecting 21" screen to LVDS connector on motherboard

Tags: connector, lcd, pinout, lvds, motherboard

I'm working in an "All-in-One pc" project. For that, I have an old Dell laptop (which only works with DC adapter) and a 21" LG monitor.
My question is: How can I connect the LCD panel directly on the motherboard? I'm looking for a cable pinout that I could use. 
With that I hope I could:

-Save the HDMI port of the motherboard for a second monitor when necessary.

-Eliminate circuit boards and save space

-Have only one ON/OFF button

-Have only one DC adapter.

This is the Dell motherboard [DNE40-CR](https://forum.laboneinside.com/viewtopic.php?t=1735) datasheet
[image: DNE40 LCD1 connector pinout]
And the LCD panel [LM230WF3](https://elektrotanya.com/lg_lm230wf3_ver.0.1_display.pdf/download.html) datasheet
[image: LG panel connector pinout]

I need some help reading those pinouts, but I already know the motherboard has more connections than I need, so we could ignore webcam and microphone.
I noticed some differences, the LCD requires 5V and the motherboard supply only 3,3V. Maybe a jumper though USB +5V could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disassemble the monitor to get the LCD panel out. You won't need the power supply board or the HDMI/VGA/whatever controller board. (carefull of high voltages, even unplug from power, the capacitors of the power board can kill you.)

The monitor panel has (probably) a LVDS interface.
Your laptop connects to LCD using a LVDS interface (if it's an old one from before ~2012)
or a eDP if it's a newer laptop. If it's eDP you will need LVDS to eDP converter board, which are very uncommon.
If it's LVDS you just need to do cable work to connect the interface correctly.

Comment: for voltage yes a jumper wire would do the trick to get 5V from the board

Answer (score 0):

Dell impression is 14". 14" is 1366x768. You risk get small image at left top coner of LCD 21".  LCD 21" is 1920x1080. If MB support resolution 1920x1080 for LVDS - you get good image. I think no. Add LCD-cable (without LCD) to MB and check LVDS resolution 1920x1080.

You must connect:

- Four odd pair  RXOC- RXOC+ RXO0+ RXO0- RXO1+ RXO1- RXO2+ RXO2+
  (for your example LVDSA_DATA#0- to FR0-, LVDSA_DATA0 to FR0+, LVDSA_CLOCK to FCLKIN+, LVDSA_#CLOCK to  FCLKIN- etc)
- Four even pair RXEC- RXEC+ RXE0+ RXE0- RXE1+ RXE1- RXE2+ RXE2+   (LVDSB_DATA#0_C to SR0M etc)
- Connect GND to pin 7,17,24 etc (and test that pinout is good)
- Connect LCD power supply (5 volts for LM230WF3).

Also... found and check LCD present signal. I do not found your "present" signal. Present signal usually connected to ground. Usually the cable connected present signal to GND directly.

If you have inverter - and powered inverter good - it's enouth to see image.

If you have LED matrix (your matrix is not LED) you must also connect VCC_LED to 12v, PWM_IN and PWM_EN  to 3v3. May be you need found this pins at inverter. Case when invertor is not working and matrix work ok can exist.

The notebook MB in some cases not accepted alien displays. LVDS_DDC_CLOCK and LVDS_DDC_DATA signal is EDID. EDID "memory" describe the matrix. May be you need i2c flash rom. May be... connect 3v3,GND,LVDS_DDC_CLOCK,LVDS_DDC_DATA to old circuit of matrix (or path of matrix) of this notebook. If the resolution of screen and resolution of MB is different - you need change flash-bios program. It's not 100% warranty that all work ok. Good luck.

> the LCD requires 5V and the motherboard supply only 3,3V. Maybe a
> jumper though USB +5V could fix it?

No. You can: Add wire to 5v (found 5v at MB, usb may be no, USB can refuse alien power supply) else add DC-DC 12to5 to 12v of backlight. DMIC_CLK_C CAMERA and other pins can be NC.

P.S. I have connected Asus prime h310t to 17" LCD N173GE-L11 directly, I have one power button, and one power supply (12 - 19 v, i7-8700T+mem+MB+tinyHDD+fan+dispay = 1,5A*12v when 0-1% CPU). The thing mini-itx MB may be intrest you.(7-8th gen:GA-IMB370TN, GA-H310TN, Asus prime h310t r20, 10th gen: Asus Pro H410T, GA-IMB410TN - all mb support 1920x1080 1600x900 1366x768 resolution setup from bios). And gigabyte have also simular model.